# Related to non-linear optics

Tags: non-linear-optics

It is said that the relation between Polarization and Electric field becomes non linear when applied electric field is comparable to interatomic field. What is its physical meaning?

Answer (score 1):

When the applied field strength approaches that of the inter-atomic fields it means that the optical field is capable of changing the properties of the media; in linear media the response is always the same, but when the media changes it's properties non-linear effects will begin to appear.